# OpenMP: Loop Carry over dependency

Tags: c++, dependencies, openmp

I am trying to implement a simple cumulative sum code in C++ as follows:

```
x[0] = 0;
for (k=1;k<100; k++)
   x[k] = x[k-1] + x[k];
```

On this [site](http://jcsites.juniata.edu/faculty/rhodes/smui/openmp.html), an implementation is noted down to eliminate the loop carry over dependency. The code should look like this for two threads:

```
x[0] = 0;
x[49] = 74; //pre calculated
//the outer loop is parallelized (two instances)
#pragma omp parallel for private(m,k)
  for(m=0;m<2;m++) {
    for (k=m*49+1; k<m*50+50; k++) {
       x[k] = x[k-1] + x[k];
    }
  }
```

The problem is I still see the loop carry dependency here (two threads running parallel, but one needs data from another).

Can somebody please add some explanation here? What is the best way to eliminate such dependency?

Comment: Have a look around SO at questions and answers concerning *parallel prefix sum*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the value of `x[49]` is already there, there is no need to compute it again: you can skip the iterations where `k = 0` and `k = 49`. That's why the loop is unfolded in two nested loops.

However, there seems to be an error there. There should only be a loop carry dependency for the inner loop, and it should propagate across iterations of the outer loop. This is because the limits are not defined properly:

- With `m = 0`, `k = 1 .. 48` (you already got 0 and 49).
- With `m = 1`, `k = 50 ..99` (again, you already got 49!).

Therefore, the loop should be left as the following:

```
for( m = 0; m < 2; m++ ) {
  for (k=m*49+1; k<m*51+49; k++) {
    x[k] = x[k-1] + x[k];
  }
}
```

If you change the addition to be:

```
x[k+1] = x[k] + x[k+1];
```

It can simplify *a bit* your lower bound...

```
for( m = 0; m < 2; m++ ) {
  for (k=m*50; k < m*51+48; k++) {
    x[k+1] = x[k] + x[k+1];
  }
}
```